# How do I intercept a message in FormFlow before it reaches recognizers? (enum usage)

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I would like to intercept what the user writes if he doesn't like any option in the list. My code is the following, but the validate function works only if the user chooses an option.

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace BotApplication.App_Code
{
    public enum MainOptions { AccessoAreaRiservata = 1, AcquistoNuovaPolizza, RinnovoPolizza, Documenti, StatoPratica, AltroArgomento }

    [Serializable]
    public class MainReq
    {
        [Prompt("Indicare la tipologia della richiesta? {||}")]
        public MainOptions? MainOption;

        public static IForm<MainReq> BuildForm()
        {
            var form = (new FormBuilder<MainReq>()

                .Field(nameof(MainOption),validate: async (state, response) =>
                        {
                            var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true };
                          {
                            string risposta = (response.ToString());
                            if (risposta  == "AltroArgomento")
                            {
                                result.Feedback = "it works only if user choose an option";
                                result.IsValid = true;
                            }
                            return result;
                          }
                        })
                .Build()); 
            return form;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask what you want your validate function to do? If you just want to change the message displayed when a user says something not in the list, you can use the [NotUnderstood template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-advanced?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#customize-prompts-using-the-template-attribute) without bothering with a validate function.

Comment: I would like to have a list of fixed choices and if the user writes a word not included in the list, The tool recognizes that and it calls a different dialog form (eg QnA). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible workarounds for you to consider. Normally if you want to account for situations where a user wants to ask a question or say something unrelated to the form, you'd have them cancel the form using the [Quit command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622773/how-to-break-formflow-in-every-moment-i-type-exit-or-cancel/52636449#52636449). If you want your bot to be smart enough to interpret when users change the subject in the middle of a form, that's a bit more advanced.

If you want to keep using a validate method, you can change your MainOption field to a `string` instead of a `MainOptions?` so that all user input gets sent to the validate method, but then you'd need to generate the list of choices yourself.

My recommendation is to use a custom prompter instead of a validate method. I've written a [blog post](https://github.com/v-kydela/BotBlog/blob/master/Blog%20-%20Making%20your%20own%20Prompter.md) that details how to make such a prompter. First you would provide a [NotUnderstood template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-advanced?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#customize-prompts-using-the-template-attribute) to indicate to your prompter when a message isn't a valid option in FormFlow. Then in the prompter you would call your QnAMaker dialog or do whatever you want with the message.

```
// Define your NotUnderstood template
[Serializable, Template(TemplateUsage.NotUnderstood, NOT_UNDERSTOOD)]
public class MainReq
{
    public const string NOT_UNDERSTOOD = "Not-understood message";

    [Prompt("Indicare la tipologia della richiesta? {||}")]
    public MainOptions? MainOption;

    public static IForm<MainReq> BuildForm()
    {
        var form = (new FormBuilder<MainReq>()
            .Prompter(PromptAsync)  // Build your form with a custom prompter
            .Build());

        return form;
    }

    private static async Task<FormPrompt> PromptAsync(IDialogContext context, FormPrompt prompt, MainReq state, IField<MainReq> field)
    {
        var preamble = context.MakeMessage();
        var promptMessage = context.MakeMessage();

        if (prompt.GenerateMessages(preamble, promptMessage))
        {
            await context.PostAsync(preamble);
        }

        // Here is where we've made a change to the default prompter.
        if (promptMessage.Text == NOT_UNDERSTOOD)
        {
            // Access the message the user typed with context.Activity
            await context.PostAsync($"Do what you want with the message: {context.Activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text}");
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync(promptMessage);
        }

        return prompt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kyle, thanks.  I used your code and it works. The only problem is that the chatbot asks the confirmation (we don't want it) is the user select a choice in the list.

Comment: thanks.  I used your code and it works. The only problem is that the chatbot asks the confirmation (we don't want it) is the user select a choice in the list.  The bot proceed to the next step only if the user answer YES (Si). 
Here is the question asked by the bot:
Questa è  la vostra scelta?
• Main Option: Acquisto Nuova Polizza
Is there a workaround that avoid the confirmation?   I tried   .Confirm("No verification will be shown", state => false)  but it doesn't work

Comment: Go ahead and include `.AddRemainingFields()`

Comment: Thanks it works and we can mix the functionalities as we like (list, free input, etc)

Comment: @Ambro - Don't forget to upvote this answer and mark it as correct